# Receiving java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: android, exception

When I run the following block of code:

```
try {
    URL surl = new URL("http://w3devadv.liveproj.com/api/apiRequest.php?Method=getdealdetails&DealId=2&SessionId=EA3JQ0RZJT4e66223143fc5");

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    SAXParser sp1 = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp1.getXMLReader();

    DealdetailsHandler dh = new DealdetailsHandler();

    xr.setContentHandler(dh);

    xr.parse(new InputSource(surl.openStream()));
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
    mue.printstacktrace();
}
```

I receive this error:

> Exc = java.net.MalformedURLException

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to load the url in your PC's browser? is it responding?

Comment: the code seems right to me, are you sure the exception originates from here?

Comment: the url is working in the browser.yes the exception is originating from there only.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look like this:

```
try {
    URL surl = new URL(
        "http://w3devadv.liveproj.com/api/apiRequest.php?Method=getdealdetails&DealId=2&SessionId=EA3JQ0RZJT4e66223143fc5");
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp1 = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp1.getXMLReader();
    DealdetailsHandler dh = new DealdetailsHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(dh);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(surl.openStream()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // Handled the exception in an appropriate way
}
```

Answer (score -2):

While using this function you need to use try catch, in that catch the MalformedURLException